# How to change text of RNGoogleSigninButton?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, react-native, google-signin

Actually I use ["this"](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin) library and default text on my GoogleSignIn button is - "Sign In".

May be some one know how to change this text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean this button: https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin/blob/master/img/signin-button.png

If yes, in code you can't change the title, because it's an image. So if you want, you can make an image like the one above but with your current text. Otherwise, you will have to redo the component that display the sign in button.